# Php get an Array in loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

how can I save values in Arry's for each index? can I do it with Sql statement or loop? 
my mssql statement:

```
 $statement = "SELECT DISTINCT cat_id,value FROM mydb where cat_id > '3000' and cat_id < '6000' order by  cat_id";
```

display my results:

```
 foreach($Sitesresults as $row)
    {
 printf("<tr><td>%s</td>     <td>%s</td>/tr>",$row['cat_id'],$row['value']);            
    }
```

I'm getting the following table:

```
### cat_id ### value
3000, 100

3000, 200

3000, 300

3000, 400   

4000, 100

4000, 300

5000, 100

5000, 200

5000, 300

5000, 400   

5000, 500

5000, 600
```

I wold like to save values of each cat_id as Array and display them as follow:

```
### cat_id ### value
3000, 100,200,300,400

4000, 100,300

5000, 100,200,300,400,500,600
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL for that

```
SELECT cat_id, group_concat(distinct value) as values
FROM mydb 
where cat_id > '3000' and cat_id < '6000'
group by cat_id
order by cat_id
```

Comment: that why I used DISTINCT in my statement

Comment: then use `group_concat(distinct value) as values`

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do, is add the values to an array [rather than display it], then you'll need to adjust your loop:

```
$container = array();
foreach ($Sitesresults as $row)
{
    $key = strval($row['cat_id']);
    if (!isset($container[$key]))
    {
        $container[$key] = array();
    }
    $container[$key][] = $row['value'];
}
```

Hope this helps.